# What is the meaning of “noexcept-expression evaluates to ‘false’ because of a call to…”?

Tags: c++

Consider the following example:

```
#include <chrono>

using T = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;

struct A
{
  A() = default;
  explicit A(T time) : time{time}
  {
  }

  T time{};
};

A foo()
{
  return A{};
}
```

When I compile this code with GCC 9.2.0, it will generate the following warning:

```
$ g++ -c noexcept.cpp -o noexcept.cpp.o --std=c++17 -Wnoexcept
noexcept.cpp:18:12: warning: noexcept-expression evaluates to ‘false’ because of a call to ‘constexpr std::chrono::time_point<_Clock, _Dur>::time_point() [with _Clock = std::chrono::_V2::system_clock; _Dur = std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> >]’ [-Wnoexcept]
   18 |   return A{};
      |            ^
```

I do not understand the meaning of this warning. It is only generated when the second constructor is in place (even though it is never called).

The warning talks about a noexcept-expression that is being evaluated. As I don’t see any such expression, I suppose there is something like an implicit noexcept-expression in the first constructor. I don’t understand why something like that should lead to a warning, though. And why does it make a difference if the second constructor is there?

Could you please shed some light onto this and explain what the problem with this code is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you explicitly opted into `-Wnoexcept`. The meaning of the flag is explained here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html

> Warn when a noexcept-expression evaluates to false because of a call to a function that does not have a non-throwing exception specification (i.e. throw() or noexcept) but is known by the compiler to never throw an exception.

In this case, I would have to guess that the compiler is implicitly evaluating a noexcept-expression involving `T{}` in order to determine whether the defaulted default constructor of `A` should be implicitly declared `noexcept`. The warning arises because the  compiler can determine that the default constructor of `time_point` never throws, yet said default constructor is not declared `noexcept`. See [here for definition](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/chrono#L679).

There is no issue with your code. The root cause of the warning is that `time_point` doesn't have the appropriate `noexcept` declaration. However, this is true for many standard library constructors, and it will take a long time to fix all of them. So, in the meantime, this warning seems to mostly add noise. If you still want to compile with this flag, you could define `A::A()` yourself as `A() noexcept {}`. (In this case you wouldn't be giving up triviality, since `T::T()` isn't trivial anyway.)

Comment: It makes a difference whether I have additionally to the default constructor the copy constructor defaulted or specified explicitly as  `A (const A& a) noexcept: time(a.time) {}` (with or without noexcept). In my understanding there should be no difference between these two. Did I missunderstand something or how does this come to pass?

Comment: @n314159 Same issue there. If the copy constructor is defaulted, the compiler will look at the copy constructors selected for the members and bases in order to compute an implicit exception specification.

Comment: Ah, I think now I understand. The warning comes only if the compiler has to guess if the constructor should be noexcept or not, hence it does matter if I tell the compiler if the constructor should be noexcept or not even if the resulting code should be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations! Because of the problems you mentioned, I chose to disable the warning for now.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a false positive diagnostic to me. Because there indeed doesn't appear to be any noexcept-expression that would evaluate to false because of that function.

P.S. The behaviour doesn't reproduce if I remove the default member initialiser from `A::time`. As far as I know, this has no semantic difference in the example program.